# Detecting all cookies sent using the setcookie function

Tags: php, cookies, header, http-headers

I have the following php code :

```
setcookie('bonjour', 'bonjour', time() + 3600); 
setcookie('aurevoir', 'aurevoir', time() + 3600);

print_r(apache_response_headers());

print_r($_COOKIE);
```

Which displays that the first time :

```
Array
(
    [X-Powered-By] => PHP/5.5.0
    [Set-Cookie] => aurevoir=aurevoir; expires=Sat, 31-Aug-2013 10:27:06 GMT; Max-Age=3600
)
Array
(
)
```

and that the second :

```
Array
(
    [X-Powered-By] => PHP/5.5.0
    [Set-Cookie] => aurevoir=aurevoir; expires=Sat, 31-Aug-2013 10:26:47 GMT; Max-Age=3600
)
Array
(
    [bonjour] => bonjour
    [aurevoir] => aurevoir
)
```

The problem is, as you can see, only the second/last cookie is stored in the Set-Cookie of the first array. So, how can I, using the headers array, detect that two cookies are set ?

Comment: "Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page load with the $_COOKIE or $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS arrays."

Comment: Yes I know but I can't access on the next page, I have to access on the same page.

Comment: cookies are set at browser end and browser needs to tell php what cookies are set. so you can get the cookie details only on the second time.

Comment: You are right @LucasWillems, I tested also, second cookie should appear also...

Comment: In fact, I get back, with curl, the headers sent by a page and I would  like to detect cookies set by this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the headers_list() function, like this:

```
<?php 
setcookie('bonjour', 'bonjour', time() + 5); 
setcookie('aurevoir', 'aurevoir', time() + 5);


var_dump(headers_list());
```

Which outputs:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.12' (length=24)
  1 => string 'Set-Cookie: bonjour=bonjour; expires=Sat, 31-Aug-2013 09:47:48 GMT' (length=66)
  2 => string 'Set-Cookie: aurevoir=aurevoir; expires=Sat, 31-Aug-2013 09:47:48 GMT' (length=68)
```

Alternativelly you could build a wrapper around setcookie function and store record about every cookie being set, but I guess previous solution should be good enough.